# DNS server doesn't work

Tags: debian, dns, bind

I'd like to run a DNS server for studying purposes but I keep getting this error message. Could you help? (virtual machine in virtualbox: eth0 - NAT, eth1 - internal adapter)

```
debianserver@debianserver:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 restart
[ ok ] Restarting bind9 (via systemctl): bind9.service.

debianserver@debianserver:~$ sudo tail /var/log/syslog
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/db.tanulas:17: near eol: unexpected end of input
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone tanulas.hu/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/db.tanulas failed: unexpected end of input
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone tanulas.hu/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone 2.0.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2016101001
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: all zones loaded
Aug 28 09:48:25 debianserver named[1787]: running
```

The file `/etc/bind/db.tanulas`:

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA debianserver.tanulas.hu. root.debianserver.tanulas.hu. (
        201610141       ;Serial
        28800   ;Refresh
        7200    ;Retry
        604800  ;Expire
        86400 ) ;Negativ cache TTL

@ IN NS debianserver.tanulas.hu.
debianserver    IN      A       192.0.2.5
@       IN      MX 10   debianserver.tanulas.hu.

ns      IN      CNAME   debianserver.tanulas.hu.
www     IN      CNAME   debianserver.tanulas.hu.
ftp     IN      CNAME   debianserver.tanulas.hu.
mail    IN      CNAME   debianserver.tanulas.hu.
ssh     IN      CNAME   debianserver.tanulas.hu.

debianserver    IN      HINFO   Linux/Jessie

win8    IN      A       192.0.2.3
```

List of edited files (following the teacher's instructions): `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`, `/etc/bind/db.tanulas`, `/etc/bind/db.2.0.192`, `/etc/resolv.conf`

By the way `/etc/resolv.conf` is always overwritten with my host's machine nameservers after every reboot. Why? It should contain

```
search tanulas.hu 
nameserver 192.0.2.5
```

but it does not.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 84.2.46.1
nameserver 84.2.44.1
```

Here is a query on the DNS server.

```
debianserver@debianserver:~$ dig @localhost tanulas.hu

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian <<>> @localhost tanulas.hu
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 35896
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tanulas.hu.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 28 14:26:31 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

`nslookup` for debianserver ends up with connection timed out.

If it counts, `udhcpd` works properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINFO must have 2 parameters: "CPU/hardware" and "OS". You have only one. Try expanding it:

```
debianserver IN HINFO Linux/Jessie makosteszta
```

Comment: Thank you/Kösz Ipor you were right. :) Yes, makosteszta is delicious, lol :) Now /var/log/syslog says everything is ok. Besides this I had to give the same IP to DHCP server as the DNS server so nslookup finds the namserver. But Network Manager still overwrites /etc/resolv.conf every time I reboot the server and it's annoying. And can I format the question like Thomas did, by myself?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The IP of DHCP server and DNS server dont have to be the same, but they need an "existing" IP of a virtual ethernet card. Furthermore NetworkManager can be modfied easily: http://askubuntu.com/questions/623940/network-manager-how-to-stop-nm-updating-etc-resolv-conf  I hope I am right now, if not please correct me.